# Rounding to the closest bin in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, rounding, binning

I have dataframe containing distances as float64 values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
binsize = 0.05
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['distance'] = [0.01555, 0.6, 0.99, 1.24]
```

This returns:

```
    distance
0   0.01555
1   0.60000
2   0.99000
3   1.24000
```

I would like to round the min and max values rounded to the closest multiple of `binsize`.

This is how I am currently doing this:

```
np.round(np.round(df['distance'].min() / binsize) * binsize, 2)
np.round(np.round(df['distance'].max() / binsize) * binsize, 2)
```

Thus returning `0.0` and `1.25` for the above example.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some old numeric tricks if you want, this gets to the same place:

```
def quick_round(binsize, item):
    return (((item + binsize / 2) * (1 / binsize)) // 1) * binsize

print(quick_round(binsize,df['distance'].min()), quick_round(binsize,df['distance'].max()))
```

Yields:

```
0.0 1.25
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Carbon. I understand that `x // 1` is equivalent to `np.floor(x)` and that `np.floor(x+0.5)` is equivalent to `np.round(x)`... Is your solution preferable to mine in the sense that it does not require numpy?

Comment: In your case I don't think it would matter, as you're just rounding the min and max, but if you had thousands of numbers to round, you can often do better with that numeric trick, as it avoids dividing each number by binsize, and floor or // 1 is likely faster than round.

Comment: Makes sense. I think that your solution is harder to read and I will likely stick to mine for the time being, but I will keep your trick in mind when dealing with a large population of numbers.